# JSONPath pattern - keeping object structure

Tags: json, parsing, jsonpath

I'm having a bit of trouble doing something with JSONPath. This is what I have:

```
[
    {
        "id": {
            "type": "literal",
            "value": "123456789",
            "datatype": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"
        },
        "name": {
            "type": "literal",
            "value": "John Doe",
            "datatype": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": {
            "type": "literal",
            "value": "2123456789",
            "datatype": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"
        },
        "name": {
             "type": "literal",
             "value": "Jane Doe",
             "datatype": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"
    }
}
```

]
}
]

And what I would like to get after applying a pattern is:

```
[
    {
        "id": "123456789",
        "name": "John Doe"

     },
     {
        "id": "2123456789",
        "name": "Jane Doe"

     }
]
```

Is this possible? The best I am doing is `["123456789", "John Doe","2123456789","Jane Doe"]`

How should the pattern look like?

Answer (score -1):

With DefiantJS (http://defianjs.com), you can query JSON structure using XPath expressions. DefiantJS extends the global object JSON with the method "search" and it returns matches as an array-like object.

Here is an example code;

```
var data = [
       {
          "id": {
             "type": "literal",
             "value": "123456789",
             "datatype": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"
          },
          "name": {
             "type": "literal",
             "value": "John Doe",
             "datatype": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"
          }
       },
       {
          "id": {
             "type": "literal",
             "value": "2123456789",
             "datatype": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"
          },
          "name": {
             "type": "literal",
             "value": "Jane Doe",
             "datatype": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"
          }
       }
    ],
    found = JSON.search(data, '//value'),
    str = '';

for (var i=0; i<found.length; i++) {
    str += found[i] +'<br/>';
}

document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = str;
```

To see this code in action, check out this fiddle; http://jsfiddle.net/hbi99/4BZMm/

For more useful XPath expressions, see the like XPath Evaluator here; http://defiantjs.com/#xpath_evaluator